Copy text SelectableRegion
Context:
I'm working with a SelectableRegion widget in Flutter. When text is selected, it opens a Context Menu with "Copy", "Select All", and a custom button called "study".
Problem:
I need to programmatically copy the selected text when my custom button is pressed, similar to how the native "Copy" button works. Alternatively, I need a way to extract the selected text to pass it to a bottom sheet that opens from my custom button.
Questions:
How can I programmatically copy the selected text within a SelectableRegion?
If direct copying isn't possible, is there a way to extract the selected text?
I've spent countless hours with Claude, ChatGPT, Google, Flutter website and google.
 buttonItems.addAll([
                                ContextMenuButtonItem(
                                  label: 'Study',
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    selectableRegionState.hideToolbar();
                                    await _copySelectedText(index);
                                    _studySelectedText(index);


Share your code or any image, I can't understand what you want.

I've added the code above to my custom Study button. My end goal is to add the selected text to my app state. I tried to copy the text and retrieve it from the clipboard but the copy doesn't work.

As I understand it, you want to show a text and the give user the ability to select a part of the text, then showing a button, when the user click on the button, you want to copy the selected text programmatically,
First:
you have to show the text by SelectableText Widget like this:
const SelectableText(
  shownText,
)

Second:
Initial a variable called selectedText with String? type
Third:
use onSelectionChanged method to detect the selection string from your shown text like this:
SelectableText(
                shownText,
                onSelectionChanged: (textSelection, selectionChangedCause) {
                  seletedText = shownText.substring(min(textSelection.start, textSelection.end), max(textSelection.start, textSelection.end));
                },
              )

Last:
in onPressed method in your button add this:
Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: seletedText));

not that Clipboard need to import services package
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

